# Power BI convert eight digit yyyymmdd to date using DAX

Tags: type-conversion, powerbi, dax

I'm trying to convert eight digit yyyymmdd to date format with DAX function.

```
column = DATE(LEFT(TABLE[COLUMN],4),MID(TABLE[COLUMN],5,2),RIGHT(TABLE[COLUMN],2))
```

However, I've got an error because of the original column has some records with "00000000", so how can I make a default value with IF statement or are there any better solution?

Best regards

Comment: I'm trying to find if there is any function check the result is date "ISDATE" or try and catch block.

Comment: Please check out "ferror" function IFERROR(value, value_if_error) for more information please visit Microsoft  MSDN with link below
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634765.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check out "ferror" function IFERROR(value, value_if_error) for more information please visit Microsoft MSDN with link below 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634765.aspx

```
column = IFERROR( DATE(LEFT(TABLE[COLUMN],4),MID(TABLE[COLUMN],5,2),RIGHT(TABLE[COLUMN],2)), DATE(yyyy,mm,dd))
```

Answer (score 5):

What I typically do is just make 2 distinct Power Query steps and this is handled automatically.

1. just make the `yyyymmdd` column a text column
2. make the text column from step 1 a date column (when prompted, be sure to select 'Add New Step')
3. replace errors with null

That's it. You can even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-Click to select multiple columns and combine them into the 1,2, and 3 steps with multiple columns.